# firebase.json rewrites issue for nodejs/vuejs firebase hosting?

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

i do not know exactly what problem i'm facing. here is my console out

[image]

I have client side and server side. In client side, developing front-end using vuejs. server side used node js/express.js for sending data to front end.

i have already deployed my project into firebase hosting. configured firebase json too.

Client side: **client-> service->Api.js**

```
  import axios from 'axios'

export default() => {
  return axios.create({
  baseURL: `https://dev-cloudthrifty-com.firebaseapp.com`
// https://dev-cloudthrifty-com.firebaseapp.com/
// http://localhost:8081
 })
```

}

Client side: **vue.config.js**

```
 const path = require('path')

 module.exports = {
  devServer: {
 compress: true,
 disableHostCheck: true,
 },
 outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'), // build all the assets inside server/dist folder
pluginOptions: {
'style-resources-loader': {
preProcessor: 'scss',
 patterns: [path.resolve(__dirname, './src/styles/global.scss')]
}
 },
chainWebpack: config => {
 if (config.plugins.has('optimize-css')) {
config.plugins.delete('optimize-css')
 }
}
}
```

**Firebase.json**

```
 {
"hosting": {
"public": "dist",
"rewrites": [
  { "source": "/", "function": "app"},
  { "source": "**", "destination": "/index.html"}
],
"ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*",
  "**/node_modules/**"
],
"headers": [ {
  "source": "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",

  "headers": [ {
    "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "value": "*"
  } ]
}, {
  "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
  "headers": [ {
    "key": "Cache-Control",
    "value": "max-age=7200"
  } ]
}, {
  "source": "404.html",
  "headers": [ {
    "key": "Cache-Control",
    "value": "max-age=300"
  } ]
} ],

"cleanUrls": true
 }
}
```

**server side: app.js**

```
   const express = require('express')
 const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
 const cors = require('cors')
 const morgan = require('morgan')
var firebase = require('firebase');
  const functions = require('firebase-functions');

 const axios = require('axios');
const credentials = new Buffer('testing:testing123').toString('base64')


  const app = express()
 app.use(morgan('combined'))
 app.use(bodyParser.json())
  app.use(cors())


  var Post = require("./models/post");

 const firebaseConfig = {
 apiKey: "AIzaSyBDwqFKPt4D0eIspjsziweLI0nc49BRDrU",
 authDomain: "cloudthrifty-demo.firebaseapp.com",
 databaseURL: "https://cloudthrifty-demo.firebaseio.com",
 projectId: "cloudthrifty-demo",
 storageBucket: "cloudthrifty-demo.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "638814042535",
appId: "1:638814042535:web:221da9fcf361554b"
 };
   firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var db = firebase.firestore();


app.get('/GCPScheduler', (req, res) => {
res.send(
[{
  title: "Hello World!",
  description: "Hi there! How are you?"
 }]
)
})
// serve dist folder
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
// Static folder
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
 // Handle SPA
 app.get('*', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));

 }

// Add new post
app.post('/list-server', (req, res) => {
 var token = req.body.token;
 var ccExp = req.body.ccExp;
 var cardNumber = req.body.cardNumber;
 var currentUserUUID = req.body.currentUserUUID;
 var amount = req.body.amount;
 console.log(token);
 console.log(ccExp);
console.log(cardNumber);
 console.log(currentUserUUID);
 console.log(amount);

(async() => {

const paymentRequest = await getAuthTokenForThePayment({
    account: cardNumber,
    merchid: '496160873888',
    amount: amount, // Smallest currency unit. e.g. 100 cents to charge $1.00
    expiry: ccExp,
    currency: 'USD'
});

const charge = await makeCharge({
    merchid: paymentRequest.data.merchid, 
    retref: paymentRequest.data.retref
});

console.log(charge);
console.log(charge.data.respstat)

if (charge.data.respstat == 'A'){

  var data = db.collection('transactionTable').doc(charge.data.retref);

  var setAlan = data.set({
    'respstat': charge.data.respstat,
    'retref': charge.data.retref,
    'account': charge.data.account,
    'token': charge.data.token,
    'batchid': charge.data.batchid,
    'amount': charge.data.amount,
    'resptext': charge.data.resptext,
    'respcode': charge.data.respcode,
    'commcard': charge.data.commcard,
    'setlstat': charge.data.setlstat,

  });

  res.send(charge.data.respstat);


} else if(charge.data.respstat == 'B'){

  console.log("Declined");
  res.send(charge.data.respstat);


}else if(charge.data.respstat == 'C'){
  console.log("Retry");
  res.send(charge.data.respstat);


}





  })();


  })
```