# how to deploy vuejs/nodejs app in firebase hosting?

Tags: node.js, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

My project structure

[image]

client part contains vue app and server part contains nodejs. In client side handling api service which is created from server. Created api services inside client folder to get response from server.

here is my structure of client-> services->api.js.

[image]

here is **client -> services -> api.js code:**

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default() => {
return axios.create({
baseURL: `https://dev-cloudthrifty-com.firebaseapp.com`
// https://dev-cloudthrifty-com.firebaseapp.com/
// http://localhost:8081
  })
}
```

**client -> vue.config.js** configuration file.

```
const path = require('path')
module.exports = {
devServer: {
compress: true,
disableHostCheck: true,
},
outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../server/dist'), // build all the assets inside server/dist folder
 pluginOptions: {
'style-resources-loader': {
  preProcessor: 'scss',
  patterns: [path.resolve(__dirname, './src/styles/global.scss')]
}
},
chainWebpack: config => {
if (config.plugins.has('optimize-css')) {
  config.plugins.delete('optimize-css')
  }
 }
}
```

Here is my firebase configuration: **firebase.json**

```
{
"hosting": {
"public": "./server/dist",
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  },
  { "source": "**", "function": "app"}

],
"ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*",
  "**/node_modules/**"
],
"headers": [ {
  "source": "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",

  "headers": [ {
    "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "value": "*"
  } ]
}, {
  "source": "**/*.@(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)",
  "headers": [ {
    "key": "Cache-Control",
    "value": "max-age=7200"
  } ]
}, {
  "source": "404.html",
  "headers": [ {
    "key": "Cache-Control",
    "value": "max-age=300"
  } ]
} ],

"cleanUrls": true
 }
}
```

**Server-> app.js** where i'm creating api for front-end

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const cors = require('cors')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const firebase = require('firebase');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const axios = require('axios');
const credentials = new Buffer('testing:testing123').toString('base64')


const app = express()
app.use(morgan('combined'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors())


var Post = require("./models/post");

const firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyDHDKttdke4WArImpRu1pIU",
authDomain: "dev-cxxxxxy-com.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://dev-cxxxx-com.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "dev-clxxxx-com",
storageBucket: "dev-cxxxx-com.appspot.com",
messagingSenderId: "830534343916",
appId: "1:83916:web:e0fd232ebb1"
};

const firebaseApp = admin.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var db = firebaseApp.firestore();

app.get('/gcp-scheduler', (req, res) => {
res.send(
[{
  title: "Hello World!",
  description: "Hi there! How are you?"
   }]
  )
})
// serve dist folder

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
// Static folder
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
// Handle SPA
app.get('**', (req, res) => res.sendFile(__dirname + '/dist/index.html'));

 }

// Add new post
app.post('/list-server', (req, res) => {
var token = req.body.token;
 var ccExp = req.body.ccExp;
var cardNumber = req.body.cardNumber;
 var currentUserUUID = req.body.currentUserUUID;
var amount = req.body.amount;
console.log(token);
console.log(ccExp);

(async() => {

const paymentRequest = await getAuthTokenForThePayment({
    account: cardNumber,
    merchid: '496160873888',
    amount: amount, // Smallest currency unit. e.g. 100 cents to charge $1.00
    expiry: ccExp,
    currency: 'USD'
});

const charge = await makeCharge({
    merchid: paymentRequest.data.merchid, 
    retref: paymentRequest.data.retref
});

console.log(charge);
console.log(charge.data.respstat)

if (charge.data.respstat == 'A'){

  var data = db.collection('transactionTable').doc(charge.data.retref);

  var setAlan = data.set({
    'respstat': charge.data.respstat,
    'retref': charge.data.retref,
    'account': charge.data.account,
    'token': charge.data.token,
    'batchid': charge.data.batchid,
    'amount': charge.data.amount,
    'resptext': charge.data.resptext,
    'respcode': charge.data.respcode,
    'commcard': charge.data.commcard,
    'setlstat': charge.data.setlstat,

  });

  res.send(charge.data.respstat);


} else if(charge.data.respstat == 'B'){

  console.log("Declined");
  res.send(charge.data.respstat);


}else if(charge.data.respstat == 'C'){
  console.log("Retry");
  res.send(charge.data.respstat);

 }

})();

})

 const getAuthTokenForThePayment = async (data) => {

try {

  const config = {
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Basic ${credentials}`
      }
  };

  const URL = 'https://fts.cardconnect.com:6443/cardconnect/rest/auth';

  return await axios.put(URL, data, config);

  } catch (error) {

  throw (error);

   }
}

  const makeCharge = async (data) => {

 try {

  const config = {
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Basic ${credentials}`
      }
  };

  const URL = 'https://fts.cardconnect.com:6443/cardconnect/rest/capture';

  return await axios.put(URL, data, config);

 } catch (error) {

  throw (error);

  }
}


 // app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8081)
exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

My issue when i click on checkout button in cart view, it should send current user card details with token to the server(app.js) through post api. After receiving card details from front-end, it should call cardconnect charge api functionality which i have implemented in app.js. In browser console current user card details received successfully but while clicking checkout charge api are not called it shows some other which is unrelated to api.

But everything works in localhost. client side localhost url: **http://localhost:8080** and server side localhost url: **http://localhost8081.**

my firebase hosting url: **https://dev-xxxx.firebaseapp.com**

here is my console output screenshot:

[image]

Dont where i am making mistakes in firebase vuejs/nodejs hosting, rewrites path.

it show error in postservice.js file

```
import Api from '@/services/Api'

export default {
 fetchPosts () {
    return Api().get('gcp-scheduler')
 },


  addPost (params) {
    return Api().post('list-server', params)
  }

 }
```

Any help much appreciated pls..

Comment: Did you update Firebase CLI $ npm install -g firebase-tools ?

Comment: my advice: use firebase callable functions (it uses Google Axios and provides context): https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

Comment: @AlexPilugin i'm new to this, may i know how to use for my code..

Comment: @AlexPilugin its warning like this Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG and GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variables are missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail
(node:32091) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

Comment: I see you have an error with "import" on your screenshot: try to use in api.js: const axios = require("axios") instead? Go to the Google Cloud Console: https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list - to see errors, go to the Firebase Console https://console.firebase.google.com/?pli=1 - in your project to see have you got free plan or you pay for it? you try to send requests to external system https://fts.cardconnect.com:6443/ui/login.jsf - you cannot do it on free plan